# x86 assembly language integer "cube root" with Newton's algorithm

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I'm writing a program that calculates the cube root of an unsigned 8-bit integer.
I'm using Newton's iteration algorithm to determine the cube root of perfect cube numbers like 1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729 and 1000.  Starting with x0 = 1, the recurrence is:

[image: Newton's iteration algorithm]

Desired execution:

Enter a perfect cube: 512
The cube root of 512 is 8

---

i have tried to write some code and im looking for some help!~ im stuck on the last 5 parts of Newton's algorithm after i get divided by 3.

```
data    segment                                                     ;data segment. Keyword db means define byte. You can also define word (dw)
        iNum    db  225                                             ;Define input number
        tStr    db 'Enter a perfect (unsigned 8-bit) cube:',10,'$'  ;Prompt for user
        oStr    db 'The result is:',10,'$'                          ;Output prompt
        iBuff   db 4, 5 dup(?)                                      ;Define input buffer
        ten     db 10       
data    ends
                        ;stack segment
stack1  segment stack       
        db  100 dup(?)  ;This is the stack of 100 bytes
stack1  ends

code    segment
        assume  cs:code, ds:data, ss:stack1

start: 
                        ;Perform initialization 
        mov ax, data    ;Put the starting address of the data segment into the ax register (must do this first)
        mov ds, ax      ;Put the starting address of the data segment into the ds register (where it belongs)
        
        mov ax, stack1  ;Put the starting address of the stack into the ax register (must do this first)
        mov ss, ax      ;Put the starting address of the stack segment into the ss register (where it belongs)

;****************** Perform Newton's Algorithm ******************

        call get_int    ;Call procedure to get user input
                                        

        mov dl, iNum    ;dl contains input number
        mov bx, 1       ;x_0 = 1    
        mov ah, 0       ;Clear ah
    
        mov al, bl      ;Move x_k into al
        mul bl          ;al = x_{k}^{2}
        mov cx, ax      ;cx = x_{k}^{2}
        mov al, dl      ;Move input into al (for division)
        div cl          ;Divide by x_{k}^{2}
        mov ah, 0       ;Clear ah (for addition)
        add al, bl      ;Add x_k
        add al, bl      ;because it's 2x
            
        mov cl, 3                   
        div cl          ;Divide by 3
                            
        cmp dl, bl                      ;Check to see if they are the same
    jne gL1S                        ;Exit loop if they are equal
    
    mov al, 1                       ;Set x_k = x_{k+1}
    jmp get_int                     ;Start again
        
    jmp print_int                   ;Output result
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                        
        mov ah, 4ch     ;Set up code to specify return to dos
        int 21h         ;Interpt number 21 (Return control to dos prompt)
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
;procedure to read an integer 
;Input None:
get_int proc                    
        mov ah, 9               ;Specify print string DOS service routine
        lea dx, tStr            ;Load pointer to string
        int 21h                 ;Call DOS service routine
            
        mov ah, 0ah             ;Prepare to call buffered keyboard input
        lea dx, iBuff           ;Load the address of the buffer into iBuff
        int 21h                 ;Request service from OS
        
        mov ah, 2               ;Specify print string DOS service routine
        mov dl, 10              ;Load new line feed into dl
        int 21h                 ;Call DOS service routine               
            
        lea si, iBuff           ;Point to start of buffer
        inc si                  ;Point to # of chars
            
        mov ch, 0               ;Clear ch for loop
        mov cl, [si]            ;Get the number of characters read
            
        add si, cx              ;Point si to end of buffer
            
        mov dl, 0               ;Clear al to create number
        mov bl, 1               ;Stores power of 10
                            
gL1S:                           ;get_int loop1 start
        mov al, [si]            ;Get digit                                  
            
        sub al, 30h             ;Convert to number
        mul bl                  ;Multiply by power of 10
        add dl, al              ;Add to total
        mov al, bl              ;Initialize X10 multiplication
        mul ten                 ;Multiply by 10
        mov bl, al              ;Store power of 10 back in bl
        dec si                  ;Decrement si
        loop gL1S               ;Loop until cx == 0
                
        mov iNum, dl            ;Store result in memory
                            
        ret
get_int endp
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
;procedure that prints out an integer passed 
;Input (al): unsigned 8-bit number for output

print_int proc
        mov ah, 9               ;Specify print string DOS service routine
        lea dx, oStr            ;Load pointer to string
        int 21h                 ;Call DOS service routine

        mov dx, '$'             ;Set up end of string
        push dx                 ;Put on stack to indicate finished      
PLS1:           
        mov ah, 0               ;Clear ah for division
        div ten                 ;Divide by 10
        mov dl, ah              ;Store remainder in dl (putting in dl makes output easier below)
        push dx                 ;Store digit for output
        cmp al, 0               ;Check to see if we are done looping
        jne PLS1                
            
        mov ah, 2h              ;Setup character output routine         
PLS2:                   
        pop dx                  ;Get last character
        cmp dl, '$'             ;Check to see if we are finished
        je pDone                ;Exit loop if equal to $
        add dl, 30h             ;Convert integer to character
        int 21h                 ;Call character output routine
        jmp PLS2                ;Continue looping
            
pDone:
        ret
print_int endp
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
code    ends

end     start
```

Comment: Newton's algorithm assumes floating point. It is a poor choice if you are doing integer arithmetic.

Comment: Note that 512 is too big for an unsigned 8-bit integer.

Comment: @NateEldredge you can go for 1, 8, 27 or 64. i was just listing!

Comment: `512` doesn't fit in an 8-bit integer.  Only numbers up to 255, if you limit yourself to 8-bit inputs.  The cube root of 65535 is about 40.3, so any 16-bit input will have a cube root that fits in 8 bits, if that helps.  (40 is tiny, so a simple linear search could work, only at worst 40 possibilities to try before finding a perfect cube, or detecting having gone past it.  Each iteration would cost 8x8 => 16-bit `mul cl` then a 16x16 => 32-bit `mul cx`, and a 16-bit compare.  Or binary search would converge fast, not as fast as Newton's but much less work per step, no division required)

Comment: Also, even for n=64, the second iterate is x_2 = 22, and then in the next step, x_2^2 overflows 8 bits.  Widening your math to 16 bits will still only get you to n=729 due to this issue.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Even with integer arithmetic, it does happen to converge to the right value for perfect cubes in the range we are discussing here, assuming overflow is avoided.  I don't know whether that would be true in general.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh. i get what u mean, if i enter 125 and the result should be 5. i know that binary search has less work but for this assignment, i have to use Newton's algorithm!~ tls for letting me know!

Comment: An initial guess other than `1` converges in significantly fewer iterations.  For numbers in the range you're looking at, `x=4` or `5` seems a good starting point, converging for n=8 in 2 or 3 iters, and for 1000 in 5 or 4 iters.  (I tried `(n>>4)|4`, but the resulting high initial guess for large n takes more iterations to converge.  Still better than x=1 which results in really big initial guesses.)  I tried these in "apcalc" aka "calc", with `define step(x, n) {return (2*x + n/(x^2))/3 }`, and stuff like  `n=1000;x=4;` then repeating `print x = step(int(x), n)` interactively.

Comment: For a 386 version, int(log2(n|2)) seems an excellent initial guess, so `or al, 2` / `bsr cx, ax` or whatever to get the position of the highest non-zero bit which is about the same thing.  Converging within a couple iterations for n = 1..10 ^ 3.  (And it's never zero thanks to the `|2`.)  cube grows faster than log2, but for these small cubes it's a very good initial guess, better than a constant or any shift.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Gz6sshqhn has compiler output for a C version that iterates `do{}while(x != old_x);`.  clang uses a multiplicative inverse for the `/3` part, GCC `-Os` uses simple `div` which might be what you want in hand-written asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have looked at ur recommended and updated the code but im not sure if it is right or not?!~

Comment: Did it work when you tested it?  That's always the first step, before asking other people about it.  (hint: `cmp dl, dl` / `je` is always going to find `dl` equal to itself, so clearly that's not right.)

Comment: Do you have a working version in C or python that you can debug with?

Comment: i tried but didnt work, it will go into an infinity loop that asks to enter cube number

Comment: Right, so single-step it in a debugger and see what's happening.

Comment: @PeterCordes i have tried to edit the code, run and got errors but dont know how to fix it

Comment: You don't seem to have a label at the top of your Newton-iteration loop, so you have nothing to jump to when they're not equal and you should keep looping.  Jumping to `gL1S` in the middle of `get_int` makes no sense; single-step in a debugger and think about where execution should go once you get to the bottom of the first iteration and the first `cmp` finds not equal, not converged yet.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> div cl        ;Divide by 3
>
> cmp dl, bl    ;Check to see if they are the same      (1)
> jne gL1S      ;Exit loop if they are equal            (2)
>
> mov al, 1     ;Set x_k = x_{k+1}                      (3)
> jmp get_int   ;Start again                            (4)
>
> jmp print_int ;Output result                          (5)
> ```

This is the part of your program that you are asking about.

- (1) What you need is to check if x_{k+1} (in `AL`) is equal to x_{k} (in `BL`). So comparing with `DL` is not going to work!
- (2) The comment says to exit the loop when they are equal but then the `jne` instruction branches on the opposite condition. Moreover, the branch jumps to the middle of the *get_int* procedure (something that you should never do). This is also a reason for why your program becomes an infinite loop.
- (3) Loading 1 into the `AL` register is not equivalent to what the comment states.
- (4) This `jmp get_int` is another reason why the program loops forever. You need to loop to where you started the calculation.
- (5) After having displayed the result, you need to return to DOS. Therefore you should use a `call` instruction here followed by invoking function 4Ch.

The calculation that you have programmed is `Y = ((N / (X * X)) + X + X) / 3`. This is correct and will work for very small perfect cube numbers like 1, 8, and 27.
Next is the amended version:

```
    mov  al, 1        ; X = 1
Again:
    mov  bl, al       ; BL = X
    mul  bl           ; AL = (X * X)                           MUL modifies AH
    mov  cl, al
    mov  al, iNum     ; N
    mov  ah, 0        ; Setup for DIV
    div  cl           ; AL = (N / (X * X))                     DIV modifies AH
    add  al, bl       ; AL = (N / (X * X)) + X
    add  al, bl       ; AL = (N / (X * X)) + X + X
    mov  cl, 3                  
    mov  ah, 0        ; Setup for DIV
    div  cl           ; AL = ((N / (X * X)) + X + X) / 3       DIV modifies AH
    cmp  al, bl
    jne  Again
    call print_int    ; Output result
    mov  ax, 4C00h    ; DOS.Terminate
    int  21h
```

### The program might encounter an additional problem

> ```
> ;Input (al): unsigned 8-bit number for output
> print_int proc
>   mov ah, 9     ;Specify print string DOS service routine
>   lea dx, oStr  ;Load pointer to string
>   int 21h       ;Call DOS service routine
> ```

In many implementations of DOS, this function 09h will return with `AL=36`. That will mess with your `AL` argument! You need to preserve it:

```
push ax
lea  dx, oStr
mov  ah, 09h
int  21h
pop  ax
```

---

### The full range

To make the calculation work for every perfect cube number in your list {1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000}, you need to widen from 8 bits to 16 bits. The `X * X` can safely ignore the high word in `DX` that you can get non-zero from using `N=1000`.

```
    mov  ax, 1        ; X = 1
Again:
    mov  bx, ax       ; BX = X
    mul  bx           ; AX = (X * X)                           MUL modifies DX
    mov  cx, ax
    mov  ax, iNum     ; N
    xor  dx, dx       ; Setup for DIV
    div  cx           ; AX = (N / (X * X))                     DIV modifies DX
    add  ax, bx       ; AX = (N / (X * X)) + X
    add  ax, bx       ; AX = (N / (X * X)) + X + X
    mov  cx, 3                  
    xor  dx, dx       ; Setup for DIV
    div  cx           ; AX = ((N / (X * X)) + X + X) / 3       DIV modifies DX
    cmp  ax, bx
    jne  Again
    call print_int    ; Output result
    mov  ax, 4C00h    ; DOS.Terminate
    int  21h
```

Comment: hello, i have tried your code and changed the print_int proc with you recommended but then i run with 216 the result is 6 with following after 1000000 and so on, i don't get where errors are!

Comment: oh nvm i got it ty!!!!

Comment: ty for helping me!~~~~~~~~~